# Fragment loses data when I navigate back to it through the up button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an activity that I have implemented using a fragment. When the app starts, it starts the activity, the activity is the launcher activity, the activity in turn loads the fragment, the fragment fetches data from sqlite database and displays it in a recycler view. But when I navigate to the settings screen(an activity) using an option menu(the gear icon shown in the images), when I will coming to the main screen again the app crashes. A methods of the recycler view adapter register the following excetions among others:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
at com.mukuha.android.snacksmenu.DataItemAdapter.getItemCount(DataItemAdapter.java:109)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4044).

Mostly it does not crash the first time but if I keep getting to settings screen and back a gain many times in quick successions to test it, like the third time or fourth it will crash. inconsistently, please help.

I am presuming the field that I have defined to be holding this data after it is fetched from the database is the one that is eventually loosing the data because the method in the adapter that is counting the number of items held there is one of them that are registering nullpointer exception. Please give reasons for a solution. Thank you in advance!
[image]

[image]

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static boolean tabletDetected;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            //app bar
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.main_activity_tittle);
    
    
            ViewGroup detailFragmentContainer = findViewById(R.id.detail_fragment_container);
            tabletDetected = (detailFragmentContainer != null);
    
    
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment_container);
    
            FragmentMain fragmentMain = new FragmentMain();
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .add(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragmentMain)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragmentMain)
                        .commit();
            }
        }
    public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {
        private static final String PARAM_KEY = "param_key";
        public static String param;
    
        private final List<DataItem> dummyDataItemList = SampleDataProvider.dataItemList;
        private List<DataItem> dataItemList;
    
        private AppDatabase db;
        private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    
        public FragmentMain() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
    
        public static FragmentMain newInstance(String containerPresence) {
            FragmentMain fragment = new FragmentMain();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(PARAM_KEY, param);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                param = getArguments().getString(PARAM_KEY);
            }
    
    //      Creating a database and loading data from a dummy data class(SampleDataProvider)
    //      into the database when the application first starts, after installing
            db = AppDatabase.getInstance(getContext());
    //      Executing database operations in a background thread
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int itemCount = db.dataItemDao().countItems();
                    if (itemCount == 0) {
                        db.dataItemDao().insertAll(dummyDataItemList);
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: data inserted");
                    } else {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: data already exists");
                    }
                }
            });
    
    //      Retrieving data from the database to display it in the RecyclerView
    //      Executing database operations in a background thread once again
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dataItemList = db.dataItemDao().retrieveAll();
    //              Dispatching data as an event to the main thread after getting it from the database
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new DataItemsEvent(dataItemList));
                }
            });
    //        Registering the EventBus
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
    
        //  Receiving the event in the main thread after it has been dispatched from the background thread
        @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
        public void dataItemsEventHandler(DataItemsEvent event) {
            dataItemList = event.getItemList();
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //      Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    
    //        Reading the settings to modify how the app displays - ( reading default preferences)
            SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
            boolean grid = settings.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_display_grid), false);
    
    //      instantiating the adapter
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragmentManager();
            DataItemAdapter adapter = new DataItemAdapter(getContext(), dataItemList, fragmentManager);
    
            RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rvItems);
            if (grid) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager((new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3)));
            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    
            return view;
        }
    }

public class DataItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    boolean tabletDetected = MainActivity.tabletDetected;
    public static final String ITEM_ID_KEY = "item_id_key";
    private final List<DataItem> mItems;
    private final Context mContext;
    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefsListener;

    public DataItemAdapter(Context context, List<DataItem> items, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mItems = items;
        this.mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        prefsListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                                                  @Nullable String s) {
                Log.i("preferences", "onSharedPreferenceChanged: " + s);
            }
        };
        settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefsListener);

        boolean grid = settings.getBoolean(mContext.getString(R.string.pref_display_grid), false);
        int layoutId = grid ? R.layout.grid_item : R.layout.list_item;

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DataItem item = mItems.get(position);

        try {
            holder.tvName.setText(item.getItemName());
            String imageFile = item.getImage();
            InputStream inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(imageFile);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (tabletDetected) {
                    FragmentDetail fragmentDetail = FragmentDetail.newInstance(item);

                    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.detail_fragment_container);

                    if (fragment == null) {
                        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .add(R.id.detail_fragment_container, fragmentDetail)
                                .commit();
                    } else {
                        mFragmentManager.popBackStack();//remove from backstack previous transaction
                        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .replace(R.id.detail_fragment_container, fragmentDetail)
                                .commit();
                    }

                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(ITEM_ID_KEY, item.getItemId());
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvName;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public View mView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemNameText);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mView = itemView;
        }
    }
}
```